# Shortest uncommon subseqence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two strings s and t,  determine length of shortest string z such that z is a subsequence of s and not a subsequence of t.

example :

s :babab,
t :babba

sol :
**3**     (aab)

not looking for copy pastable code, please if anybody can help with intution for solving this.

thanks a lot !

Comment: usa a dp array may solve the problem. Same idea with the classic `longest common subseqence` problem

Comment: Have you made any effort towards the solution or are you just looking for someone to give a copy-pastable one?

Comment: actually not looking for copy pastable code, just the intution or hint for solving this . i've tried to come up with a recursive solution first but that didn't worked so

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I created on IEnumarable method which gives back all possible combinations. This is compared with t. I optimized the solution to loop only once over the not match String t.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GuessTheNumber
{
    public class Element:IComparable<Element>
    {
        public string Seq { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Element other)
        {
            return this.Seq.CompareTo(other.Seq);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "babab";
            string t = "babba";
            string z = ShortestUncommonSuqsequence(s, t);
        }

        static public string ShortestUncommonSuqsequence(string SubSequenceOf, string NotSubSequenceOf)
        {
            var uniqueSeq = new SortedList<Element, int>();
            uniqueSeq.Add(new Element() { Seq = "", Id = -1 }, -1);

            foreach (Element oneSequence in GetNextUniqueSequences(uniqueSeq, SubSequenceOf))
            {
                int index = oneSequence.Id + 1;
                while (index < NotSubSequenceOf.Length)
                {
                    char NotChar = NotSubSequenceOf[index];
                    if (oneSequence.Seq[oneSequence.Seq.Length - 1] == NotChar) break;
                    index++;
                }
                if (index == NotSubSequenceOf.Length)
                {
                    return oneSequence.Seq;
                }
                else
                {
                    oneSequence.Id = index;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        static public IEnumerable<Element> GetNextUniqueSequences(SortedList<Element, int> UniqueSeq, string Input)
        {
            SortedList<Element, int> results = new SortedList<Element, int>();
            foreach (var prevResult in UniqueSeq)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Input.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (prevResult.Value < prevResult.Key.Seq.Length + i)
                    {
                        string nextStr = prevResult.Key.Seq + Input[i].ToString();
                        Element newElem = new Element() { Seq = nextStr, Id = prevResult.Key.Id };
                        if (!results.Keys.Contains(newElem))
                        {
                            results.Add(newElem, prevResult.Key.Seq.Length + i);
                            yield return newElem;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (Input.Length > 1)
            {
                foreach (Element res in GetNextUniqueSequences(results, Input.Substring(1)))
                {
                    yield return res;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for effort !                                                                                            
but the problem here might be that this solution is sort of a brute force one, also exponential in nature.

Comment: Its returning the earliest shortest match. Although it looks like brute force it is coded in ienumerable and jimps pur of loops as soon as possible..

Comment: Optimized to the fullest, if you like the answer please accept.